# installing a package for pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I installed Eclipse and would like to addd cvxopt module to it. I have tried a lot but always got the following error:

```
No module define as cvxopt
```

How can I overcome this problem? I have MAC OS lion 10.7.5 and the installed python version is 
2.7.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you follow the instructions stated here: http://cvxopt.org/install/ ?

Comment: yes, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your module is somehow not in the PYTHONPATH... can you check if it works in the command line? (i.e.: start shell and do import cvxopt in it)

If it does, you may want to check your environment:

Print in the command line and inside of Eclipse:

```
import sys
print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.path)))
```

and see where it differs.

Comment: I did it and I got no difference. The result of import cvx is as follows:       Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-10-14abf1b564a4>", line 1, in <module>
    import cvxopt

ImportError: No module named cvxopt

Comment: Where is cvxopt in your filesystem? Can you show the output of the print for sys.path?

Comment: This is the result:  import sys
sys.path
Out[3]: 
['',
 '/Users/Star/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/utils/external',
 '/Users/Star/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources',
 '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7',
 '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',

Comment: '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/site-packages.zip',
 '/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Users/Star/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/Users/Star/.ipython']

Comment: And where is cvxopt in your system?

Comment: How can I find the path for cvxopt?

Comment: Well... if you don't know where you installed it you may try to use find to search for it...